# connect switch to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have set my modem in [bridge mode](http://www.rogers.com/web/support/internet/home-networking/247?setLanguage=en), but this only allows 1 port to work. I need more than 1 port for connections to other places in my home, so I was trying to use a switch connected to the one port of the modem, and from there connect the router and other devices. However, when I do this my router is not working (I have no wifi), but my other devices that are connected directly to the switch work fine. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? I this even possible? The router is for sure function properly, as when I connect it directly to the modem, wifi is working fine.

Just for clarification this is what I am trying to do:

```
                             ->Router -> Wifi

Bridged Modem -> Switch ->   ->Device 1

                             ->Device 2
```

Comment: Yes you are wrong, if you connect at this way, all your device will ask for a Internet IP address, but your Internet plan is usually only include one IP address. Is it a 4port wireless wifi router? If so you can place it after bridged modem

Comment: As mentioned, basically just switch your Router and Switch in the diagram and everything should be good

Answer (score 1):

Your design does not work because of what a switch does, and what a router does. The bridge will connect a private network to a public network. A network is identified with network addresses (IP addresses usually). Switches are not designed to provide or manipulate network IP addresses. That is the job of a router. On the port connected from the router to the bridge (as it should be configured) you will have a "public" IP address. On the ports on the other side you will have private IP addresses (including WiFi in your case).
The bridge connects to the Router and one of the ports on the router will connect to the switch. The two devices will need to be plugged into the switch. This is how your network will function using consumer grade equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but to add to Everett's answer here, a Layer 3 switch would need implemented. Layer 3 switches handle packets at the IP address level, thus giving them the ability to route traffic via IP address.

Your topology should be something like:

Modem -> Bridge -> L3 Switch -> Router/Firewall -> Devices

Also: Make sure your Router is also a dedicated firewall.

Comment: No, it won’t. A Layer 3 switch is not a router with switch built in. A Layer 3 switch is a router that uses certain protocols (like MPLS and VPLS). It has to be connected to a network provider that is configured to route these protocols. The correct answer has already been provided, you have not added to it.